# Regex for Hebrew, English, Symbols

Tags: c#, regex, detect

as part of a small program i'm writing i need to filter a String input that might be "gibrish" (any sign in UTF8)
the input can be hebrew and/or english but also have all the normal signs like : ?%$!@'_' and so on...

a friend suggested to use regex, but due to my inexperience with using it i come to you for advice.

how can i create a C# function to check an input text and if it's not "right" return false

my try so far is:

```
public static bool shortTest(string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"^[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתץףןםa-zA-Z0-9\_]+$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        return regex.IsMatch(input);
    }
```

all the chars after "[" and to "a" are hebrew

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Why don't you just include the remaining signs in the character class? (btw, you don't need to escape the underscore)

Comment: @m.buettner, as i sad... never used regex, friend gave me the code and i try to see how to make it work for my purpose. right now i have a dual "foreach" char compare function that does the trick but poorly made, so i wanted to use regex

Comment: The question remains: what's not working with the code as it stands?

Answer (score 9):

For **Hebrew letters**, in **C#** you can do somthing like that:

```
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[א-ת]+$");
```

enjoy =)

Comment: for more possibilities like ` בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית ` see [that](https://jcuenod.github.io/bibletech/2017/08/19/matching-hebrew-unicode-regex/) awesome article

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\p{IsHebrew}` character class instead of enumerate all hebrew characters, \w for [a-zA-Z0-9_] and \s for spaces, tabs, newlines. You can add too dots, comma... An example :

```
^[\p{IsHebrew}\w\s,.?!;:-]+$
```

or

```
^[\p{IsHebrew}\w\s\p{P}]+$
```

\p{P} stands for all ponctuation signs (as far i know: `.,?!:;-_(){}[]\/'"&#@%*`)

Comment: tried, got this error "parsing "^[\p{Hebrew}\w\s,.?!;:-]++$" - Unknown property 'Hebrew'."

Comment: @ian: try with the prefix `Is` as in my edited post, directly in your code

Comment: with the 'is' i get "parsing "^[\p{IsHebrew}\w\s\p{P}]++$" - Nested quantifier +."

Comment: what does the +$ at the end? 
does \s matches tabs and newlines also?